# straddling tomcat and django

Tags: java, python, django, tomcat

I'm working on a webapp project that was originally written using jsp, tomcat, jersey and eclipselink. I think that we should move the project towards django. There is one component of it that needs to be almost completely rewritten. It would be great if I could rewrite that portion using python and django's database models but have it still be called by the existing java codebase.

Can anyone suggest a reasonable method to do this? Is this kind of mixed system a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a terrible, terrible idea, and yet morbidly fascinating at the same time. Anyway...

["Running Django on Jython"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/)

["Using Jython Within Java Applications"](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html)

Do keep us informed on your progress.

Comment: I think you might be right. If I do it I will build it as it's own webservice but have it only accept contacts from localhost... but I don't think this is the sort of thing I"ll be able to sell to management.